# Properties of random variables with $E[ \sin(X+Z) \sin(3X+Z)]=0. $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Let $X$ and $Z$ be two independent symmetric random variables such that
\begin{align}
E[ \sin(X+Z) \sin(3X+Z)]=0. 
\end{align}

From the above identity ca we say something about the distributions of $X$ and $Z$? Or is it hopeless? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Where does this $E[ \sin(X+Z) \sin(3X+Z)]=0$ come from?